# Why does the "activated" signal never call the lambda function assigned to the Gtk.Action?

Tags: gtk3, vala

Using vala and glade ui, I have no signal signatures assigned in glade. However I did make a Gtk.Action object in glade with a name of "new_action":

```
<object class="GtkAction" id="new_action">
    <property name="label" translatable="yes">New</property>
    <property name="short_label" translatable="yes">New</property>
    <property name="tooltip" translatable="yes">Create a new DESKTOP file</property>
    <property name="stock_id">gtk-new</property>
    <property name="is_important">True</property>
</object>
```

Later, here is the button that uses the "new_action":

```
<object class="GtkToolButton" id="new_toolbutton">
    <property name="related_action">new_action</property>
    <property name="visible">True</property>
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="related_action">new_action</property>
    <property name="label" translatable="yes">New</property>
    <property name="use_underline">True</property>
</object>
```

In the code I first get the Gtk.Builder:

```
Gtk.Builder builder.add_from_file ("azoth.ui");
```

Then I create my action object and assign the lambda function:

```
this.connect_components (); /* my code - shown below in this question */
this.builder.connect_signals (this);
```

Then in vala (using the Gtk.Builder) I assign a var new_action from the builder:

```
this.new_action = this.builder.get_object ("new_action") as Gtk.Action;
```

Then later I create a lambda for it in the code:

```
this.new_action.activate.connect (() => {
   stdout.printf ("You activated the NEW action!\n");
}
```

When running, I click on the "New" button and no output is generated to stdout. I feel like  I may be missing a step as the concept is simple and should be easy to generate action callbacks in the code without having to define the callback in glade.

Comment: Why are you calling connect_signals() here?

Comment: I was not 100% sure I needed to call it, since I am not defining any signals in glade. However it makes no difference to my issue.

Comment: Are you keeping the gtkbuilder alive or it's being destroyed?